# SQL query - duplicate values + added information

Tags: sql

I need to identify duplicate values for a table, which is not a problem through `count` and `group by` function, however I need added information there.

```
CUSTOMERS               TRANSACTIONS    
cust_id cust_code       cust_id    trans_id

1       AB12            2          1
2       B12             3          2
3       AB22            2          3
4       B12             1          4
```

I need to find duplicate customer codes (`cust_code`) from table `CUSTOMERS`, which I can do with query

```
select a.cust_code, count(*)
from CUSTOMERS a
group by a.cust_code
having count(*) > 1
```

Part I'm not sure how to tackle is to get data from table `TRANSACTIONS` in the result.

Now `cust_code` value `'B12'` appears twice in  table `CUSTOMERS` and should be represented. I am looking to add the `MAX` trans_id value from table `TRANSACTIONS`.

Is this possible at all? I suppose the result should be something like:

```
cust_id cust_code   trans_id

2           B12         3
4           B12         0
```

`max trans_id` for `cust_id 2` is `3` and `max trans_id` for `cust_id 4` is `0` (no transactions for cust_id 4)

I would not have a problem in finding the `max` value for this either, although I'm not sure how to retain the duplicate `cust_code` criteria.

Not 100% sure on the database engine, however I believe it to be something from IBM.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

```
Select c.*, T.trans from
Select a.cust_code, count(*) from CUSTOMERS a
Group by a.cust_code
Having count(*) > 1) c
Left outer join
(Select cust_code, max(id) as trans from transactions
Group by cust_code) t
On c.cust_id = t.cust_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join this query on an aggregate query from the `transactions` table:

```
SELECT    cust_code, cnt, COALESCE(trans, 0)
FROM      (SELECT   cust_id, cust_code, COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM     customers
           GROUP BY cust_code
           HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1) a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   cust_id, MAX(trans_id) AS trans
           FROM     transactions
           GROUP BY cust_id) b ON a.cust_id = b.cust_id
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution using your query as well is the following:

```
SELECT 
   c.cust_id,
   c.cust_code,
   COALESCE(tt.max_id, 0)
FROM
(
    select a.cust_code, count(*) cnt
    from CUSTOMERS a
    group by a.cust_code
    having count(*) > 1
) t
JOIN customers c ON c.cust_code = t.cust_code
LEFT JOIN (
    select cust_id, MAX(trans_id) max_id
    from transactions
    group by cust_id
) tt ON c.cust_id = tt.cust_id
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8e4a22a5be7eb328dc6f27447fe35d1c)

Answer (score 0):

just do this

```
 select a.*,ifnull(max(c.trans_id),0) as trans_id from Customer a join
 (select cust_code,count(*) cnt from Customer group by 1 having cnt>1) b
 on a.cust_code=b.cust_code
 left join
 transaction c on a.cust_id=c.cust_id
```